# Armazenar dados em STRUCT e imprimir dados na tela - 3 pessoas

Tags: c, struct

Alguém sabe me dizer o que estou fazendo de errado? Eu preciso armazenar os dados de 3 pessoas em **struct** e depois imprimir.

Está aparecendo esse erro:

> request for member ‘nome’ in something not a structure or union|
>   request for member ‘idade’ in something not a structure or union|
>   request for member ‘peso’ in something not a structure or union|
>   request for member ‘altura’ in something not a structure or union|
>   request for member ‘vetor’ in something not a structure or union|

Mas não entendi o que está errado ainda.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

     struct pessoas {

        char nome[20];
        int idade;
        float peso;
        float altura;

    };

    struct pessoas usuario[3];

    int i;

    for (i=0; i<=2; i++)
    {

        printf("\n");
        printf("\nDigite seu nome: ");
        gets(usuario.nome);

        printf("\nDigite sua idade: ");
        scanf("%i", &usuario.idade);
        fflush(stdin);

        printf("\nDigite seu peso: ");
        scanf("%f", &usuario.peso);
        fflush(stdin);

        printf("\nDigite sua altura: ");
        scanf("%f", &usuario.altura);
        fflush(stdin);
    }

    for (i=0; i<=2; i++)
    {
      printf("\n%s, com %i anos voce pesa %.2f e tem %.2f de altura!", usuario.vetor[i], usuario[i].idade, usuario[i].peso, usuario[i].altura);

    }
    printf("\n\n");
    return(0);
}
```

Desde já, agradeço. ;)

Comment: `usuario` é um array: tem elementos. Não é uma struct, não tem membros. Suponho que queres qualquer coisa como `usuario[0].nome`. *Oh! Nunca uses `gets()`. É impossível usar com segurança e há uma função alternativa que podes usar com segurança: `fgets()`*

Comment: Ah, ok. Vou começar a usar o fgets() então, obrigada. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Além da utilização do `fgets()` recomendada pelo @pmg encontrei dois erros no seu código.
Primeiro você faz um vetor de `structs` mas não acessa os elementos da `struct` como vetores. Segundo na hora de exibir você passa como primeira variável a ser exibida `usuario.vetor[i]` que não existe. Para solucionar estes problemas faça assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

     struct pessoas {

        char nome[20];
        int idade;
        float peso;
        float altura;

    };

    struct pessoas usuario[3];

    int i;

    for (i=0; i<=2; i++)
    {

        printf("\n");
        printf("\nDigite seu nome: ");
        fgets(usuario[i].nome, sizeof(usuario[i].nome), stdin);

        printf("\nDigite sua idade: ");
        scanf("%i", &usuario[i].idade);
        fflush(stdin);

        printf("\nDigite seu peso: ");
        scanf("%f", &usuario[i].peso);
        fflush(stdin);

        printf("\nDigite sua altura: ");
        scanf("%f", &usuario[i].altura);
        fflush(stdin);
    }

    for (i=0; i<=2; i++)
    {
      printf("\n%s, com %i anos voce pesa %.2f e tem %.2f de altura!",usuario[i].nome, usuario[i].idade, usuario[i].peso, usuario[i].altura);

    }
    printf("\n\n");
    return(0);
}
```

Desta forma os erros apontados não aparecem e o código compila.

Comment: Entendi...Muito obrigada, vou tentar fazer desse jeito aqui. ;)

Comment: Eu tentei aqui, mas quando ele volta na segunda vez no for ele não lê o nome, vai direto pra idade. :/

Comment: Então, depois que eu inseria um numero inteiro ele voltava no for e pulava direto pedindo a idade, acabei de conseguir resolver isso colocando um  getchar(); depois do ultimo scanf.